# jnlp files not launching anymore

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

I want to launch a program from the browser using webstart, and for that I have a .jnlp file that looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" 
      codebase="http://localhost:8080/webstart/"
      href="ncb-client.jnlp">

   <information>
      <title>Title</title>
      <vendor>Vendor</vendor>
      <homepage href="http://www.example.com/"/>
      <description>Description</description>
      <icon href="example.gif"/>
   </information>

   <resources>
      <j2se version="1.7+" />
      <jar href="MyProgram.jar"/>
   </resources>
   <security>
      <all-permissions/>
   </security>
   <application-desc main-class="com.Mainclass">
   <argument>server.address</argument> 
   <argument>rmi://localhost:1111?http=:8080</argument>
   <argument>client.rmi.ssl.truststore</argument>
   <argument>C:\keystore</argument>
```

I am pretty sure that the .jnlp file is correct as it worked one day and the following day didn't work anymore. By not working I mean that in Firefox instead of launching the program I just get the .jnlp text opened in a second tab. In Chrome I get this in another tab:

```
Vendor Title server.address description server.address rmi://localhost:1111?http=:8080 client.rmi.ssl.truststore C:\keystore
```

I don't know what can have changed in the system from one day to another, without me changing anything. If I try to execute the jnlp I get the following exception and of course the app doesn't start:

```
java.io.IOException: Invalid Http response
```

Can anybody think of something that I'm doing wrong or can have changed in my system to make this not to work?

Comment: Is it possibile that the JNLP download the application from an application server that it is not working anymore?

Comment: nope, I run it in my machine

Comment: Have you updated your Java installation? Maybe something was broken in the update process. Or have you updated your browsers?

Comment: Have you searched for the last error in SO? I found these link: [Webstart https: works with server on certificate and not on loadbalancer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368753/webstart-https-works-with-server-on-certificate-and-not-on-loadbalancer), [GlassFish and Application Client Web Start: invalid Http response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19190891/glassfish-and-application-client-web-start-invalid-http-response), [Java Web Start Jar signing Issue?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673707/java-web-start-jar-signing-issue)

Comment: your jnlp file is missing the closing </jnlp> tag

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).  Besides the problem mentioned by @SaeidNourian, it also has other problems that need fixing.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your help, some of your answers have helped me finding the problem by thinking further.
The problem is that there was a change in the web server and wouldn't serve .jnlp files correctly anymore.